# apex:dynamiccomponent returning a value

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-vf-component

I am tying to achieve pagination using command buttons as dynamic components. but i want to return the value of the button number to my controller so it can return the same page. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: If I got it correctly, can't it be done with a variable that will be set in the button action?

Comment: Yeah.. u might be right.. but how? i mean its a dynamic component. I'm working with it for the first time and m kinda lost... Can u pls help?

Comment: If your solution doesn't work out, and assuming your data is read-only, another way to paginate (and to get a bunch of other features "for free") is to use JavaScript and specifically https://www.datatables.net/. If the volume of data is limited it can be generated into the page and if it is large it can be loaded via JSON.

Comment: My data isn't read only. It is a questionnaire where the buttons demonstrate the questions numbers.

Comment: What you mean by the 'Same Page'? If this is a pagination, anyway this is about one page isn't it? you need to change the content only. Also are you getting the questions from the database?

Answer (score 2):

Okay so assuming I am understanding the question you are asking.  I have a solution.

You need to change your thinking just a small amount and you got this!

Instead of passing the value of the button back to the controller, you can pass the page controller/extension to the Dynamic Component.

Example:

Say I have the following controller...

```
public class ctrl_myPage extends ApexPages.StandardSetController {
    // Properites
    public String        pageNumber {get; set;}
    public List<Integer> numPages   {get; set;}

    // Property Getter Methods
    public ctrlMyPage getCurrentCtrl() {  return this;  }  // Use "{!currentCtrl}" in a VF page to pass your current controller instance to your dynamic component.

    // ... Constructor and more ... //

    // Action Methods
    public PageReference getSelectedPage() {
        this.setPageSize(this.pageNumber);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then I can create a Dynamic Visualforce component that makes use of `<apex:attribute>` tags to access the controller properties and methods.

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:attribute name="myPageCtrl" type="ctrl_myPage" required="true" description="the controller with pagination support" />
    <apex:attribute name="panel"      type="String"      required="true" description="Panel to refresh when new page is choosen" />

    <apex:repeat value={!myPageCtrl.numPages} var="pageNum" >
        <apex:commandLink action="{!myPageCtrl.getSelectedPage}" rerender="{!panel}" value="{!pageNum}">
            <apex:param name="pageNumber" value="{!pageNum}" assignTo="{!myPageCtrl.pageNumber}" />
        </apex:commandLink>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:component>
```

Then all we have left is to create our visualforce page!

```
<apex:page controller="ctrl_myPage">
    <c:DynamicPaginator myPageCtrl="{!currentCtrl}" panel="{!pagePanel}" />
    <apex:outputPanel id="pagePanel">
        <!-- All the page contents go here! -->
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

A few things to note:

- I used `<apex:outputLink>` tags instead of `<apex:commandButton>` tags because they support the `<apex:param>` tags.
- You can use CSS to style an `<apex:outputLink>` as a button
- When doing anything in VF I like to keep the [Standard Component Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_compref.htm) open as I work. (Use the Navigation Panel on the left to expand the list.)
- This will really help you understand the apex tags I used and how they interact.